画像を含めた投稿を成功させたい
状況
rails tuotorial １３章 4.1 基本多岐な画像のアップロード 学習、実装中です。
コードは記載のものをコピペして実装したのですが、以下のエラーとなります。
buildメソッドの引数に関しては複数受け付ける想定で、後述するパラメータの内容で問題ないはずですが、引数数のエラーが出ます。

これ以前の実装はすべて済んでいます。
エラー該当箇所
/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb
.
.
.
  def create
    @debug = micropost_params
    # binding.pry
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)　//　ここでエラー
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
.
.
.

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end


環境
rails v7.0.4.3
ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
virtualboxにubuntu入れて、ローカルのwin11からssh接続して開発しています。
一つ変則なのは、railsのバージョンは上記ですが、学習教材のrails tutorialはv5.1のものを参照しています。ただ、これはあまり関係ないのでは、と推測しています。
（gemのインストールは正常、エラー内容がrailsネイティブなメソッドのエラーのため）
試したこと
パラメータ（micropost_params）について、正常系と異常系で中身を確認しました。
異常系のほうの、pictureが引数として余分、という意味のエラーと解釈しています。が、本章の趣旨的にこの引数を受け取ってもらわないと実装できません。buildメソッドに関する理解に不足があるかもしれません。

正常系
rails tutorial 13.4.1で画像を含める投稿実装前。テキストのみの投稿

#<ActionController::Parameters {"content"=>"d"} permitted: true>


異常系
13.4.1実装後。画像を含めた投稿

 #<ActionController::Parameters {"content"=>"d", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007c6177faded0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20240512-9797-eh3w7u.jpg>, @original_filename="Blue_flower_by_Elena_Stravoravdi.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"micropost[picture]\"; filename=\"Blue_flower_by_Elena_Stravoravdi.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: true>


補足資料

問題発生したrails tutorialの13章
rails buildドキュメント


参照している Rails Tutorial のページには「 最新版 をご利用ください」と注意書きが表示されています。Rails バージョンの差がどの程度影響するのかは詳しくないのでわかりませんが、手順に沿って試すのであれば、ひとまず環境を揃えるべきだと思います。
